# Need to Hide or clode the window while printing the current page in php Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Here, Am having one booking form for which contain several input fields with print button. while filling the booking form all fields gets stored in to the database.(here am using ajax to store the data to db).In ajax by getting success message, need to get last insert id for retrieve the last insert record which is from mysql db.After that, i passed that id to controller to the view. In that view page, am calling printcontent in body load function. Every thing is working fine. but need to hide the open window. need to get the print booked ticket without opening window.I have attached my jquery code below,check my code and let me know. 
My jquery code:

```
        <script>

            $( document ).ready(function() {
             printcontent($(".dvData").html());
             //$(".dvData").hide();
            });


            function printcontent(content)
            {
                var mywindow;
                var mywindow = window.open('', 'mywindow', 'width:210mm; height:148mm;');
                //$('.dvData').css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
                mywindow.document.write('<html><body>');
                mywindow.document.write(content);
                mywindow.document.write('</body></html>'); 

                mywindow.document.close(); 

                mywindow.print();
                alert("Trip Sheet Printed Successfully");
                //mywindow.style.visibility = 'hidden';

                return true;
            }
            </script>
```

Thanks @

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function PrintPanel() {
       var panel = document.getElementById("<%=Panel1.ClientID%>");
       var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=120,width=300');
       printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>YOUR TITLE</title>');
       printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
       printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
       printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
       printWindow.document.close();
       setTimeout(function () {
           printWindow.focus();
           printWindow.print();
           printWindow.close();
       }, 500);
    return false;
 }
```

or set your function to `return false;`at the end of codes